# asp:DropDownList to asp.net MVC Syntax (boostrap HTML)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Could someone please help translate the syntax below from aspx to browser readable HTML?

I inherited an aspx file but currently integrating the old html into the MVC clean html, the probvlem comes with foreign syntax that are not being read by the browser.

example;

```
<asp:Literal   ID="11" Text="Full Name"></asp:Literal>
<asp:DropDownList   ID="id1" CssClass="form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the list of

```
SelectListItems
```

to the page as model (let's say they have car names and a field called CarName)
and do

```
@Html.DropDownList("CarName")
```

Then MVC does the rest for you.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

The HTML should be something like:

```
<form action="/Home/Cars" method="get">

<fieldset>Movie Type <select id="CarName" name="CarName">

<option value=""></option>

<option value="0">Ferrari</option>

<option value="1">Burago</option>

<option selected="selected" value="2">Lamborghini</option>

<option value="3">Maserati</option>

</select>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </p>

</fieldset>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple form you can use the below form

```
<form action="/Home/CategoryChosen" method="get">

<fieldset>Movie Type <select id="MovieType" name="MovieType">

<option value=""></option>

<option value="0">Action</option>

<option value="1">Drama</option>

<option selected="selected" value="2">Comedy</option>

<option value="3">Science Fiction</option>

</select>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </p>

</fieldset>

</form>
```

But I would recommend the below code.

In your Controller add this code.

```
public ActionResult SelectCategory() {

     List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Action", Value = "0"});

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Drama", Value = "1" });

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Comedy", Value = "2", Selected = true });

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Science Fiction", Value = "3" });

     ViewBag.MovieType = items;

     return View();

 }
```

In your View add the below code.

```
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Category Select";

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Simple_Layout.cshtml";

}

@using (Html.BeginForm("CategoryChosen", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {

    <fieldset>

            Movie Type

            @Html.DropDownList("MovieType")

        <p>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        </p>

    </fieldset>

}
```

For reference follow the Microsoft [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Clean html will look something like this:

```
<p id="11">Full Name</p>
<select id="id1" class="form-control"></select>
```

Not sure that there is an equivalent of `AppendDataBoundItems` parameter in html.

If you want to use MVC html syntax, this code will look something like this:

```
@Html.Label("Full Name", new { id = "11" })
@Html.DropDownList("<name of the list in the model>", new { @class="form-control", id = "id1"})
```

Note that you should pass the list for dropdown in the model and put the name of this list as the first parameter in `@Html.DropDownList` function. You can read more about it [here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor).

Comment: your answer just put me back on the right track since the drop down items are generated from an uploaded excel file (first row data)